# ReactNative: how can I add two dynamic values to single object

Tags: react-native

I want to add two valued to data objects like this

const data = {
"folderPath": data1,data2
}

result I want:

const data = {
"folderPath": "14,0"
}

14, 0 which comes from data1, data2

please any one help me

Answer (score 0):

const data = { "folderPath": `${data1},${data2}` }

Answer (score 0):

A simple as that:

```
const data = { folderPath: [data1, data2].join(',') };
```